# Yii search by one value in many_many relation, and get all data from this relation

Tags: php, yii, relation

I have three table `product` , `category` , `product_category`

and in product model I add this relation

`return array(
                'categories' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Category',
                'product_category(product_id, category_id)')
        );`

Now I want to use search by category if category select.

In product `actionIndex` i add this code

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
if($_GET['name'])
{
    $criteria->with = array('categories');
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->addCondition('categories.name = :name');
    $criteria->params = array(':name'=>$_GET['name']);
}

$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Product',array(
        'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>10,
        ),
        'criteria' => $criteria
));

$this->render('index',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
));
```

If i made search, categories loads in eager load, and has no categories other than searching.
How search Product by category, but in `$data->categories` has all categories, without loads them by second relation in view, how Andrey Vorobyev says?

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer

if i use `$criteria->with = array('categories'=>array('select' => false)) and call $data->categories`, it do lazy loading and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, that i think, is make two same relations with different names: one for search, another for show.
Because, when we set condition, we filter post by category, and we can't get all categories.
But you will have one more relation, you can get all categories in lazy load, when you were print posts.

Comment: i want all category for each post, not all category

Comment: DataProvider need you to show Product, right? No categories. DataProvider retrieve data about Products, not about all categories. Show, code, that print info about categories.

Comment: `<?php foreach ($data->categories as $category):?>
  <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($category->name),'category/'.$category->name); ?>
  <?php endforeach;?>`  now i want if select category with **same** view file , show all category for each post

Comment: What you mean with same view file? I am don't understand that.

Comment: i have a view php file for index ( show all product ) i want use this php file too , if search by category selected, so if category selected `$data->categories` not work fine.

Comment: Ok, then you can refer to view categories, by `$this->render('index',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'categories' => $categories
));`, and in view you can use `$categories` not `$data->categories`

Comment: how i get `$categories` for each post ?? your answer return all category, i want categories for post

Comment: I am subscribe on your question, because i am intresting too =).
We must find the best way)

Comment: I found answer, if i use `$criteria->with = array('categories'=>array('select' => false))` and call $data->categories, it do lazy loading